# Match amd replace 'http://*' with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a text with multiple wildcards in it. I want to delete `http://*`.

I tried `sed -i '/http://*/d' file`, reverse grep but the * is ,

Can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```sh
sed -i 's~http://\*~~g' file
sed -i 's~https\{0,1\}://\*~~g' file
```

Here:

- `-i` - modifies the file inline
- `s` - defines the `s`ubstitution command
- `~` is used as a regex delimiter char (to avoid escaping `/` chars in the pattern)
- `http://` matches a literal string
- `\*` matches a `*` char (it needs escaping as it is a special regex metachar)
- `g` - `g`lobal flag to remove multiple occurrences per line.

In the second command, `s\{0,1\}` matches an optional `s` in the protocal pattern part.

Comment: Thank You! Specially for breaking down the commands.